Circa 1950-60 short story about a scientist who builds a machine to create a woman
A super shy scientist built a machine to make a woman. The first success disappeared after 5 seconds. Poof!
She was naked.
He improved the machine. A woman  appeared in evening dress but he couldn’t take her further than the stairs before. Poof.
He found the glitch. Produced a ravishing beauty took her to dinner then bed. That’s when he found the machine had forgotten something…

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you read this in a magazine or an anthology?

Sounds like a Fredric Brown story

The details don't match, except for the basic ones, but I am reminded of the recent question we had regarding the scientist who created a matter creation machine, asked for a girl, and accidentally got a very young girl, with his next exclamation leading to them both being burnt to a crisp.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/284296/inventor-creates-wishing-machine-accidentally-calls-up-hell which is indeed a Fredric Brown story.

Which was asked by me !  I note though that Brown sold to Playboy, and this could be a Playboy story

Huh, and my quick search turned up https://www.blackgate.com/2013/11/04/vintage-treasures-the-best-of-fredric-brown/, which references the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/287200/23243. Go figure.

What had the machine forgotten? You can't remember the ending?

The machine forgot to make her capable of sexual relations, if I'm recalling the story correctly

@Andrew In real life a young woman with just such a deformity once became pregnant. https://abcnews.go.com/Health/Wellness/teen-girl-vagina-pregnant-sperm-survival-oral-sex/story?id=9732562
